# Does the forgetful functor from ${\rm Ab}$ to ${\rm Grp}$ preserve coequalizers?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups

Let $f, g$ morphisms from $G$ to $H$ abelian groups. The coequalizer $C$ in ${\rm Grp}$ will be an abelian group.

Must it coincide with the coequalizer in ${\rm Ab}$?

It seems like it should because given $\alpha : H \to X$ that coequalizes $f, g$ we are forced to send elements of $C$ to the image of $\alpha$ which is abelian.

Is there a simpler argument to prove this, or am I wrong?

Comment: Note that the forgetful functor $U: Ab \to Grp$ is fully faithful. As such it reflects all limits and colimits.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName I don't see how that helps here. This would mean that if the coequalizer is abelian then it coincides with the coequalizer in Ab, right? But my question is in the opposite direction.

Comment: Hm, I must have misunderstood. The phrase "The coequalizer C in Grp will be an abelian group. Must it coincide with the coequalizer in Ab?" is a bit confusing in that case.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName Perhaps it was me who made confusion, apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is true. The universal property in the category of groups implies the universal property in the category of abelian groups so long as the coequaliser in the category of groups is abelian.

The easiest proof is to show that the coequaliser (in the category of groups) is $H/K$ where $K$ is the normal subgroup generated by $f(g)h(g)^{-1}$. Indeed, the quotient map $H\to H/K$ coequalises $f,g$ and any map $\alpha:H\to X$ which coequalises $f,g$ has kernel containing $K$. Therefore there is a unique map $\beta:H/K\to X$ which makes the diagram commute.

Now when $H$ is abelian, $H/K$ is too. So you are done.